# Issue while performing merge/mosaic of multiple TIFF files using Rioxarray Python

Tags: python, rasterio, rioxarray

I am trying the following code to mosaic/merge 10 image files (.tif files) using the following code:

```
import rioxarray
from rioxarray import merge
from rasterio.plot import show

items = [r'D:\LC08_L1TP_146046_20180425_20180502_01_T1.tif',
r'D:\LE07_L1TP_145045_20180426_20180523_01_T1.tif',
r'D:\LC08_L1TP_144046_20180427_20180502_01_T1.tif',
r'D:\LC08_L1TP_144045_20180427_20180502_01_T1.tif',
r'D:\LC08_L1TP_143046_20180420_20180502_01_T1.tif',
r'D:\LC08_L1TP_143047_20180420_20180502_01_T1.tif',
r'D:\LC08_L1TP_143045_20180420_20180502_01_T1.tif',
r'D:\LE07_L1TP_145046_20180426_20180523_01_T1.tif',
r'D:\LE07_L1TP_145045_20180426_20180523_01_T1.tif',
r'D:\LC08_L1TP_144047_20180427_20180502_01_T1.tif']

elements = []

for val in items:
    elements.append(rioxarray.open_rasterio(val))

merged = merge.merge_arrays(elements, nodata=0.0)

image = merged.values
show(image)
```

After running the above code I am getting the following plot:
[image: Image after running above code]

The image shown above is not the correct mosaic/merge image as the left and right part of the image is swapped because when I am loading the input files in ArcMap I am getting the following:

[image: Input Files as seen in ArcMap]

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: It looks like two different UTM zones are spanned, so the western half is east of the eastern half.

Comment: @Vince. Your suggestion was correct. It was because of Projection difference (difference in UTM zones between input images) because of which mosaic was not happening properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cross posted: https://github.com/corteva/rioxarray/issues/172

I see that you have both EPSG:32643 and EPSG:32644 as the CRS of the datasets. The merge function assumes that they are all the same CRS.

You need to change:

```py
for val in items:
    elements.append(rioxarray.open_rasterio(val))
```

to:

```py
for val in items:
    rds = rioxarray.open_rasterio(val)
    if rds.rio.crs != "EPSG:32643":
        rds = rds.rio.reproject("EPSG:32643")
    elements.append(rds)
```

Comment: After using your suggestion I got following error: "AttributeError: 'DataArray' object has no attribute 'crs'". So changing "rds.crs" to "rds.rio.crs" solve the issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Good catch, glad you were able to find the fix 